# how to draw line between to points using mapKit in xcode 6

Tags: iphone, ios8

I am new to iOS development and I am using XCode 6.

I want to draw a route between two locations on map, like a tour guide. When the tourist clicks another location I want to be able to draw a route; as well as, inform about the distance from the current location.

Comment: I have one question: which process you like to implement?

Comment: 1) MKMapKit Direction API.
2) Google Route API for draw path.

Comment: Google route API for  draw path.

Comment: Are you able to draw a route or want some help. I am asking this because your mark answer to accepted. Tell me if you need any help.

Comment: yes, i am able to draw a route map. this code is really helpful for me .

Comment: but i need some other help on core data. will you help me?

Comment: are you not able to find similar question on stack for core data problem then please post a question or attached an question link. I will help on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know about your question is that you want to draw a route between two Locations.
TO achieve this First Make Two  `UITexfield` to take source and destination and one `UIButton` to perform action.
Connect All outlets

Don't Forger to add Map Framework.

> ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>


@interface ViewController : UIViewController<MKMapViewDelegate>
 {

 IBOutlet UITextField *source1;
 IBOutlet UITextField *destination1;
 IBOutlet MKMapView *map;
 MKAnnotationView *Annotation;

 }
-(CLLocationCoordinate2D)FindCoordinates:(NSString *)place;
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id)overlay;
-(IBAction)getLocation:(id)sender;

 @end
```

> ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"


@interface ViewController ()

{
  CLLocationCoordinate2D myLocation;
  CLLocationCoordinate2D sourceLocation;
  CLLocationCoordinate2D destinationLocation;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

}


-(CLLocationCoordinate2D)FindCoordinates:(NSString *)place
{

NSString *addresss = place;
NSString *esc_addr = [addresss stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *req = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=%@", esc_addr];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:req]];


NSDictionary  *googleResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

NSDictionary *resultsDict = [googleResponse valueForKey:  @"results"];   // get the results dictionary
NSDictionary *geometryDict = [   resultsDict valueForKey: @"geometry"];   // geometry dictionary within the  results dictionary
NSDictionary *locationDict = [  geometryDict valueForKey: @"location"];   // location dictionary within the geometry dictionary

// nslo (@”– returning latitude & longitude from google –”);

NSArray *latArray = [locationDict valueForKey: @"lat"]; NSString *latString = [latArray lastObject];     // (one element) array entries provided by the json parser
NSArray *lngArray = [locationDict valueForKey: @"lng"]; NSString *lngString = [lngArray lastObject];     // (one element) array entries provided by the json parser

myLocation.latitude = [latString doubleValue];     // the json parser uses NSArrays which don’t support “doubleValue”
myLocation.longitude = [lngString doubleValue];

return myLocation;

}

-(IBAction)getLocation:(id)sender
{
sourceLocation = [self FindCoordinates:source1.text];
NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Source lat:%f Source lon:%f",sourceLocation.latitude,sourceLocation.longitude]);
destinationLocation = [self FindCoordinates:destination1.text];
NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Desti lat:%f Desti lon:%f",destinationLocation.latitude,destinationLocation.longitude]);

CLLocation *loc1 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:sourceLocation.latitude longitude:sourceLocation.longitude];
CLLocation *loc2 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:destinationLocation.latitude longitude:destinationLocation.longitude];
CLLocationDistance distance = [loc1 distanceFromLocation:loc2];
NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Distance iin KMeteres %f",distance/1000]); // Gives me air distance


}


@end
```